# WCF Ria Services assemblies problem

Tags: c#, .net, wcf-ria-services

I have problem with WCF Ria Services libraries. I want my project to use assemblies of RIA Services locally in my Lib folder where all external referenced assemblies are. I don't want to be dependent on installation of the services. And in my opinion it is better for later updates of the services.

I've found assemblies that my app is referenced to, put them in my lib folder, then deleted references from my csproj, and changed it to the assembly in my lib folder. The problem is that in properties window of the changed reference it did't change the location to file. I tried to change it several times but after change it shows

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\RIA
>   Services\v1.0\Libraries\Silverlight\System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.dll",

but I changed the path to

> "D:\Work\MyProj\Libs\System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.dll"

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up your .csproj file so that you can see the XML (unload the project and click on edit).

For the references to the WCF RIA dlls check that you have a  to where you have placed the dlls.

When you have ensured that the paths to the dlls are where you want reload the project. In the references highlight one of the dlls and look at the location in its properties, it should agree.